# Facebook API search for hashtag does not show all the post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, posts, hashtag

I am fetching all public post with specific hashtag. The problem is that the result only shows some of the post but not all.

It is any restrictions or rules in what post are indexed and show in the "search".

I'm using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=myhashtag&type=post.

What I can see so far is that in the facebook page when I search for the hashtag I have some results and they are different that the ones the api returns.

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have written.